# Best way to join up d40 pipe from kitchen sink to sewer to fix leak

Tags: kitchen-sink, pipe-fitting

So this is the current situation. The corrugated pipe does fit into the sewage mains but every now and then it back leaks. I am hesitant between an O'Ring or a Pipe clamp. Could you let let know what do you think is the best solution to make this join water tight.
[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a P-trap on the hose?  Smooth solid pipe usually does not catch stuff as much as corrugated pipe and is easier to seal to other pipes.

Comment: Thanks there is a P-trap section further up on the hose indeed- so would you suggest then replacing the corrugated pipe with a smooth one down from the p-trap? what would you suggest for the join with the Soil and Vent pipe ? thanks !

Comment: Where does it leak ?

Comment: @RohitGupta, It leaks out in the junction of the two pipes, as the corrugated one goes on the inside but the seal is not fully tight, i.e. no O'ring nor nothing like that.

Comment: @DanielVieira is that solid piece at the wall attached to the corrugated hose, or is that what the corrugated hose is inserted to (i.e. it's glued to the pipe inside the wall)?

Comment: @Huesmann thanks! it is the latter - i.e the solid piece is glued to the pipe inside the wall and the corrugated hose inserts into it

Comment: So the leak is likely ocurring between the corrugated part and the solid connector.  Were I you, I'd attempt to replace the corrugated hose with solid pipe that could be connected with a slip joint connector, or even some kind of shielded Fernco, at the wall connector.